# How should this hole in concrete/stone be repaired?

Tags: repair, exterior, hole

While doing a routine home inspection I found this hole in the exterior wall of the home.  If I understand the structure correctly, there is a concrete or stone foundation to the exterior walls and a large beam sitting across a rock at the center of the home in the crawlspace which has a supporting wall above it on the main floor.  The hole is quite deep, at least 4 or 5 inches.[image][image]

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like a hole to me.  It looks more like there is no footer.  The concrete was poured on the existing ground and the ground has since settled, exposing the bottom of the concrete.  Or perhaps multiple pours, one on top of the other, and there was a pocket in that spot.

Comment: Hi and thanks.  I dug down further (see 3rd photo) and the foundation wall goes down further into the ground, so it seems like your second theory is more likely.  Is this a large problem?  Do you have any repair suggestions?  I prodded with a longer tool and it's at least a foot deep.

Comment: This appears to be a very old house. If it hasn't been a problem up until now it is not likely to be one anytime soon.

Comment: I don't see any obvious settlement cracks above that area in the pictures, so it doesn't look like there's a current problem.  The only way to be sure, and to determine what, if any repairs are warranted, is to have a professional look at it.